# Deleted all users in WSL

Tags: sudo, root, users, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I seem to have accidentally deleted all users on my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS setup. Now, I've created a new user "tetemp" which I wish I hadn't done. Unfortunately, I cannot add a user "root" back.

Here's the current entry in **passwd**:

```
tetemp:x:1000:100::/home/tetemp:
```

When I try to add "root" user, I get the following errors:

```bash
$ adduser root
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
$ sudo adduser root
sudo: unknown user: root
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I can't change passwd because it is read only.

- How can I regain access to the "root" user?
- Is it possible to delete the "tetemp" user.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You could just wipe the WSL image and start over again. That would be the fastest way to get things operational again.

Comment: What happens when you just run `wsl` (or `wsl <distro>`)?  I just set up a new Ubuntu instance, created a new (second) user, deleted everything but that user from `/etc/passwd`.  After exiting, I'm still UID 0 when I start the instance back up and can edit `/etc/passwd` in that state.  I *cannot*, however, start up as `wsl -u root`, but I can without `-u root`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I can edit passwd because its read only. and i try `-u root`
PS C:\Users\Kullanic> wsl -u root =>
User not found.

Comment: @Atduyar Okay, I can reproduce it now, at least.  I think I had to add the user *after* deleting `/etc/passwd`.  The last time I added the user while `/etc/passwd` was still intact, then deleted all lines *but* the `tetemp` user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's tough.  The usual `wsl -u root` recovery mechanism won't work without the `root` user in `/etc/passwd`, and when `tetemp` was added, it became the default user (with no `sudo` permissions).

I see two paths forward, at least.  Either create a new instance (and copy files over) or attempt to recover the broken one:

- First, after trying this in a test instance, I *can* still access the instance under Windows using the `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` path.  That won't let you fix `/etc/passwd`, but it will at least let you copy out any files you need to recover from the instance.

  You can install a second instance of the exact same Ubuntu distribution you installed from the Store:

  1. Start PowerShell as an administrator
  2. Run:

     ```
      Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\' | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'install.tar.gz' }
     ```
  3. The output will have the location of the `install.tar.gz` that was used to create the original instance.
  4. Create a directory where the new instance will be created.  I use something like `%userprofile%\WSL\NewUbuntu`.
  5. From a regular, non-admin PowerShell, run

     ```
     wsl --import NewUbuntu ".\path\to\WSL\NewUbuntu" "<path_with_tarball>\intall.tar.gz" --version 2`
     ```
  6. Start the new instance using `wsl -d NewUbuntu`.  You'll be `root` by default.
  7. Add your regular user with:

     ```
     adduser <username>
     usermod -aG adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,netdev <username>
     ```

     This is the set of groups that is created for the default user in Ubuntu on WSL.
  8. Make this user the default in WSL by creating `/etc/wsl.conf` as mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).

  You should now be able to copy over files from your old instance (`\\wsl$\Ubuntu`) to the new one (`\\wsl$\NewUbuntu`).

  Ultimately, to delete the old copy, when you are *sure* you have all your critical files out, `wsl --unregister <distroname>`.

There are possible options that I can think of that might allow you to *repair/recover* the existing instance.  I have not tested these step-by-step, but most everything here is something I've done at one time or another:

- This one I don't recommend, as it has the *potential* to leave the instance in an unstable state ultimately:

  - Convert the instance to WSL1 using `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1`
  - In Windows, navigate to the location of the WSL1 overlay file system in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Canonical...\LocalState\rootfs\etc\passwd`.
  - Fix your `/etc/passwd` using a Windows app that handles Linux line-endings.  Again, this can be problematic, as it can ultimately [cause filesystem corruption in WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/). It might be easiest and safest to just *delete* the `passwd` file, since we believe that doing so will let you log in as UID 0 again and then re-create the `root` user.
  - Convert it back to WSL2, if desired.
- Or, use another instance to fix the first:

  - Create a tarball of your broken instance with `wsl --export Ubuntu fixme.tar`.
  - Go back to the first option above where we created a new instance and do those steps.  But call the instance something like "UbuntuTemp".
  - Inside that new (temporary) instance:

    ```
    mkdir ~/fixme
    cd ~/fixme
    sudo tar --xattrs-include="security.capability" -xvf /mnt/c/path/to/fixme.tar
    sudo cp /etc/passwd ~/fixme/etc/passwd
    sudo tar --xattrs -cvf /mnt/c/path/to/fixed.tar .
    ```
  - Exit the temporary Ubuntu instance.
  - In PowerShell, create a directory for your fixed Ubuntu instance, then:

    ```
    wsl --import Ubuntu20_04 "path/you/just/created" "path/to/fixed.tar" --version 2
    ```
  - Start the fixed (hopefully) instance with `wsl -d Ubuntu20_04`.
  - Set your regular user as the default using `/etc/wsl.conf` per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).
  - Assuming that it is working correctly, set the instance as the default using:

    ```
    wsl --set-default Ubuntu20_04
    ```